# Treat results duplicates with UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, bdd

I have a problem with this query:

```
Select id count(*)
....
....
....
....
UNION
Select id count(*)
.....
.....
.....
.....
```

And the output is:

```
04123158->  32
04123158->  17
04123412->  36
04132010->  1473
```

I need the output be like the following:

```
04123158->  49
04123412->  36
04132010->  1473
```

The problem appears when using two similar ids with UNION. I would like to have one only result with the sum.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `union` (really `union all`) and then aggregation:

```
select id, sum(cnt)
from ((select id, count(*) as cnt . . .
      ) union all
      (select is, count(*) as cnt . . .
      )
     ) i
group by id
```

Note:  You want `union all` for two reasons.  First, `union` removes duplicates.  So, if two `id`s had the same value for `count(*)`, then `union` would remove one of the rows.  `Union all` does not remove duplicates.

Second, `union` removes duplicates.  This incurs unnecessary overhead in the query.  Why add additional performance overhead?

Comment: mmmm I dont understand very well because my english is not very good (Sorry)
I need to do a union because I have 2 tables similar in structure but different in datas...
The 1º select is about relation with tables (with less than 30 days) and the 2º select contains datas older than 30 days...

You say that union removes duplicates but why in my case didnt do ??

Comment: @user5552354 - The two rows you are wanting to combine are not "duplicates", they just have the same value for one of the columns. In your example, you are wanting to group : `04123158->  32` and `04123158->  17`. Both rows share the value `04123158` for the first column, but are different for the second column. A duplicate would be if both rows were identical for all columns (for example : `04123158->  32` and `04123158->  32`).